# How can i express concentration in this ODE ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So as you can see in this photo, i want to express ci (output concentration of mixture) as a function of time.
Qi, Cu, K, xv, V - known facts.

I know this is an easy work, but my math has become rusty.

[Problem with expressing ci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMYXh.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac V{Q_i}\frac {dc_i}{dt}+c_i=\frac {C_uK}{Q_i}X_\nu$$
Multiply both side by $\frac {Q_i}V$ 
$$\frac {dc_i}{dt}+c_i\frac {Q_i}V=\frac {C_uK}{V}X_\nu$$

It's a first order differential equation

I use method of integration factor with $\mu(t)= e^{\frac {Q_it}V}$

Multiply both sides by $\mu $
$$(c_i e^{\frac {Q_it}V})'=\frac {C_uK}{V}X_\nu e^{\frac {Q_it}V}$$
Integrate both side
$$c_i e^{\frac {Q_it}V}=\int \frac {C_uK}{V}X_\nu e^{\frac {Q_it}V} dt$$
Put the cionstants outside of the integral

$$c_i e^{\frac {Q_it}V}=\frac {C_uK}{V}X_\nu \int  e^{\frac {Q_it}V}dt$$
Evaluate the integral on the right side

$$c_i e^{\frac {Q_it}V}=\frac {C_uK}{V}X_\nu e^{\frac {Q_it}V}\frac V{Q_i}+C$$
Finally
$$c_i =\left ( \frac {{C_uK}X_\nu}{Q_i} +Ce^{\frac {-Q_it}V}\right )$$

Where C is a constant of inetgration  to be determinated at $t=0$ for example

---

***Edit1***

Note that you can write the differential equation simply this way

$$\frac {dc_i}{dt}+c_i\frac {Q_i}V=m $$

where

$$m=\frac {C_uK}{V}X_\nu$$
Since you only have a constant on the right side of the equation